# How to pass a JS loop variable into a FireStore get

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to pass a variable during a for loop into a firebase database, however it comes back as the same value in each loop, I've commented in the code, where the issues happen.

```js
    var countElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-voteCount]");

    function displayVotes() { 

    for (i = 0; i < countElements.length; i++) {
                    
        var elementID = countElements[i].dataset.votecount;
        
        docRef = firestore.doc("Votes/product-" + elementID);
        
        console.log(elementID); // when it's logged here the ID's are correct. 
        
         docRef.get().then(function(doc) { // how do i pass it into here?? 

            if (doc.exists) {
                
                console.log('document exists ' + elementID); // when logged here the ID is always 1 

            }
             
             else {
                 
                console.log('document not found ' + elementID); // when logged here the ID is always 1 

            }

            });

        }

    }
```

```html
<div data-voteCount="1"></div>
<div data-voteCount="2"></div>
<div data-voteCount="3"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you give a try for async/await instead of .then()?

Comment: have you checked if you are getting the right values for countElements

Comment: @MuthuThavamani That's it! Thanks!

Comment: @sonali Yeah, they were coming through okay, see the answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would write something like this:

```
async function displayVotes() { 

  const countElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-voteCount]");

  for (let i = 0; i < countElements.length; i++) {
    const elementID = countElements[i].dataset.votecount;
    const id = `Votes/product-${elementID}`;
    const docSnapshot = await firestore.doc(id).get();
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      console.log(`document exists: ${elementID}`);
    } 
    else {
      console.log(`document not found: ${elementID}`);
    }
  }
}
```

I converted to the `async-await` syntax, so you get more control of when things are going to happen. The downside is that you'll get a waterfall execution, 1 call will be made, then the other, and so on... If you want them to run in parallel, your can use `Promise.all()` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Awesome! This is spot on, much cleaner! I'l take a look into the promise but there's no real necessity they run parallel on this project. Really appreciate the help!